# IIS Removing Authorization Header from Outgoing Requests

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, asp.net-web-api, soap

I am developing a REST API (ASP.NET Web API) wrapper over an existing SOAP XML service. Idea is my API gets a request from a client, and then internally calls the existing SOAP API, does some operation on the response received and returns the modified data as RESTful response to the client. The SOAP service is hosted on a different server. I am using the proxy classes generated from the WSDLs of the SOAP service in my web API. I am adding an authorization header programatically to the SOAP request -

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> GetHttpHeader()
    {
        string userName = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        string passWord = "xxxx";

        var httpHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        httpHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + passWord)));
        // httpHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        return httpHeaders;
    }
```

This header is being added to EndpointBehavior before sending the request like this -

```
        try
        {
            req.TargetBranch = Constants.TargetBranch;
            var httpHeaders = GetHttpHeader();
            client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new HttpHeadersEndpointBehavior(httpHeaders));

            lowFareSearchRsp = client.service(null, req);

            return rsp;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                
            client.Abort();
            throw e;
        }
```

This works fine when ran from Visual Studio. But problem starts to appear when I host this in IIS. I have tried IIS 7.5 and IIS 10.0.

My Application pool is using built in Identity - LocalSystem and the REST API is hosted with pass through authentication. I have tried other combinations as well - same result.

I have used fiddler to compare the header of the request to SOAP - when running from Visual Studio and when running the application from IIS.

The clear difference is the header that I am adding to the SOAP service request is not present in case of the IIS outgoing request.

I am puzzled - can anybody tell me what is going wrong here?